# How to get decimal values in jsp page?

Tags: jsp, struts2

Datatype is **BigDecimal** having value like- **10.0000**

While I am printing in JSP page using

```
<s:property value="%{account.totAmt}"/> -> I am getting just 10, but I want to get whole number i.e 10.0000

<s:textfield id="price" name="account.totAmt" />  -> here I am getting 10.undefined, but I want to get whole number i.e 10.0000
```

Note: **It was working fine with the older version of struts2 but after migrating to v. 2.5.26 it is not working**.

Comment: It's possible there's an OGNL issue that went undetected; I'll check.

Comment: It is not an issue. If it is then post a # here.

Answer (score 0):

Use getText method like shown below:

```
<s:property value="getText('format.number2', {account.totAmt}  )"/>
```

Add the property to the **struts.properties** file:

```
format.number2={0,number,#0.00##}
```